# hex packages location on linux

Tags: linux, elixir, elixir-mix

I'm scanning an Elixir project by reading the `mix.lock` file and parsing the output of `mix deps.tree` command.  Later on I need to locate each dependency's `.tar` file.  On my windows machine the location is inside the `C:\Users\{user-name}\.hex\packages\hexpm` folder. 
However on my linux machine, the `.hex` folder contains only `cache.ets` file, but no `packages` folder.  Searching for `.tar` files returns nothing relevant.

Any idea where are those files hiding?
cheers,
eRez

Comment: Hi, in my case I couldn't find my `.tar` files in `~/<my_project>/.hex/packages` either. My folder `.hex` was as you described it. I found my `.tar` files one directory above (i.e. `~/.hex/packages`). Could it be the case that you find you `.tar` files in a different `.hex` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Should be under in your home: `~/.hex`

But the archives seems to be located in `~/.mix/archives/`

For example, if I try to upgrade my hex:

```
~ > mix local.hex
Found existing entry: /home/meox/.mix/archives/hex-0.18.1
```

Comment: Thank you.  you're right - it should be under `~/.hex` but its not, and the archives under `./mix/archives` are no use for me, i'm after the `.tar` files of the dependencies (which should be under `~/.hex/packages/hexpm`)

Answer (score 0):

You can find that on `~/.hex/packages/hexpm`.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the project on which a ran my tests was the first hex project on that machine, and running the `mix deps.get` didn't result any `.tar` files in the cache as expected, but when i switched to a different project all was back to normal and indeed everything as under `~/.hex/packages/hexpm`